# User doesn't update Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Update Method:

```
public function update(UserUpdateRequest $request, Users $uzytkownik)
    {
        $this->authorize('update', $uzytkownik);

        if ( $uzytkownik->update([
            'birth' => $request->birth,
            'sex' => $request->sex,
            'about' => $request->about,
        ]) )
        {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

On update here in page `1` appears. Like it did the thing.
But in db nothing has changed.

`$uzytkownik` is proper user, and
This is the `dd($uzytkownik);`

[image]

And below `dd($request->birth.'---'.$request->sex.'---'.$request->about);` which shows proper inputs

[image]

Why it doesn't work properly?

Comment: Have you made those columns fillable in the model ?

Comment: As Sagar suggested, fillable array must be correctly filled to use update and create methods

Comment: Laravel's update() and create() functions return the model, whether it was saved successfully or not. You can use the save() function which will return you a useful boolean that you can use in that if() statement.

Comment: Are you using transaction ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#updates)

> Mass Assignment
>   You may also use the create method to save a new model in a single line. The inserted model instance will be returned to you from the method. However, before doing so, you will need to specify either a fillable or guarded attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default.

You need to make sure `$fillable` or `$guarded` is correctly set otherwise changes may not be persistant.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want like this too:

```
public function update(UserUpdateRequest $request, Users $uzytkownik)
{
    $this->authorize('update', $uzytkownik);

    $uzytkownik->birth = $request->birth;
    $uzytkownik->sex   = $request->sex;
    $uzytkownik->about = $request->about;

    if ( $uzytkownik->save() )
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That seems like a lot more effort every time you want to update an object when all you need to do is keep the modal attributes up to date

Comment: Maybe, but it looks to me the OP wants to return 1 or 0 depending on whether the model was saved or not. And this is much more easy then retrieving the model again and comparing it to make sure all attributes were correctly persisted to the database.

Comment: I guess the problem lies somewhere else, any errors in the logs?